# Bias-variance decomposition for random variables taking values in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to recover the bias-variance decomposition in Hilbert space. Below is my understanding.  Could you have a check on it?

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_H, | \cdot |_H)$ a Hilbert space . It follows that $L_2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{L_2}$ defined by
$$
\langle X, Y \rangle_{L_2} := \int_{\Omega} \langle X(\omega), Y(\omega) \rangle_H \mathrm d P(\omega) = \mathbb E_{P} \langle X, Y \rangle_H.
$$

Let $| \cdot |_{L_2}$ be the induced norm of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{L_2}$. Then $|X|_{L_2} = [\mathbb E |X|^2_H]^{1/2}$. We define covariance by
$$
\operatorname{Cov} (X,Y) := \langle X, Y \rangle_{L_2} - \langle \mathbb E X, \mathbb EY \rangle_{H}.
$$

Clearly, $\operatorname{Cov}$ is a bilinear form. It follows that $\operatorname{Var} X := \operatorname{Cov} (X,X) = |X|^2_{L_2} - |\mathbb E X|^2_{H}$ and that $\operatorname{Var} X \le \mathbb E |X|^2_H$. Fix $x \in H$. We have $$
\operatorname{Var} [X -x] = |X-x|^2_{L_2} - |\mathbb E X -x|^2_{H},
$$
and thus
$$
|X-x|^2_{L_2} = |\mathbb E X -x|^2_{H} + \operatorname{Var} X.
$$

The bias-variance decomposition then follows, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb E |X-x|^2_H = |\mathbb E X -x|^2_{H} + \operatorname{Var} X.
$$